# Как поменять хранение сессии в файле на куки Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, cookie, сессия, cart

Всем привет! Есть корзина реализована на сессиях, изначально планировал сделать что то типа хранения корзины в сессии для не авторизованых пользователей и в БД для авторизованных, но решил не заморачиваться и подумываю как бы сделать ее на куки. Корзина уже готова, вот пример добавления в корзину:

```
public function addCart(Request $request, $id){
      $product = Product::find($id);
      $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : NULL;
      $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
      $cart->add($product, $product->id);

      $request = Session::put('cart', $cart);

      Session::flash('add-product', $product->name);

      return redirect()->back();
    }
```

```
public function add($item, $id){
      $storedItem = [
        'qty' => 0,
        'id' => $item->id,
        'prod_url' => $item->url,
        'code_cat' => $item->category->code,
        'url_cat' => $item->category->url,
        'name' => $item->name,
        'cost' => $item->price,
        'price' => $item->price,
        'img' => $item->cardImage->path
      ];
      if($this->items){
        if(array_key_exists($id, $this->items)){
          $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
        }
      }
        $storedItem['qty']++;
        $storedItem['cost'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
    }
```

Посмотрев доки нашел, что благодаря env параметру `SESSION_DRIVER=file` и в файле `session.php` `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file')` сессия хранится в файле, но ее можно заменить на куки. Так вот, как это сделать только для корзины? И как знать, какие еще параметры хранятся в сессии?

Comment: А зачем такое извращение? Насколько помню лара не делит сессии, вы сами можете писать в куки что хотите через фасад печенек или функцию `cookie()` и `$request->cookie()`

Comment: В целом вы в самом начале правильно думали, только сделайте корзину для всех в бд, и там храните идентификатор пользователя если нулл то это гость, если есть идентификатор то это пользователь а в куки/сессии храните лишь идентификатор самой корзины

Comment: Насколько правильно хранить товары корзины всех пользователей в БД? Она ведь перегружена будет. Да и как я заметил, в БД хранят товары корзины крупные проекты, а нужно ли это для небольшого интернет магазина? Человек зашел, посмотрел либо сразу либо немного позже купил. Думаю куки тут в самый раз ИМХО.
Вы сказали "а в куки/сессии храните лишь идентификатор самой корзины", это для чего, что то сообразить не могу?

Comment: Идентификатор корзины в плане id с бд, даже на мелких проектах такое встречается мы для одного из своих клиентов просто делали мусорщик который удаляет устаревшие корзины, а надо ему это что бы понимать где брошеная корзина, возмонжо этот клиент совершил ещё что то на сайте или звонок заказал а менеджер уже знает что он хотел купить и на основе корзины делает заказ